# How do I remove an element from an array in a case-insensitive way?

Tags: arrays, ruby, case-insensitive, removeall

I’m suing Ruby 2.3.  When I want to remove a string element from an array by value, I can do

```
2.3.0 :005 > a.delete("AB")
 => "AB"
```

but how do I remove the element in a case-insensitive way?  That is, how can I make

```
a.delete(“ab”)
```

behave like

```
a.delete(“AB”)
```

?

Comment: In future, consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections may discourage other answers and short-circuit those still preparing answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours, some wait much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `delete_if`

```
a.delete_if { |s| s.downcase == 'ab' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question says "remove *an* element" which implies you only want to remove one element when duplicates exist. If that is your intent (and there may be duplicates), you can remove the first or last instance thusly:

```
arr = ['aB', 'cd', 'Ab', 'ef']

def delete_first(arr, target)
  ndx = arr.index { |s| s.downcase == target }
  ndx.nil? > nil : arr.delete_at(ndx)
end

delete_first(arr, 'ab')
  #=> "aB" 
arr
  #=> ["cd", "Ab", "ef"] 

delete_first(arr, 'de')
  #=> nil 
arr
  #=> ["aB", "cd", "Ab", "ef"]
```

To delete the last instance of `target` in `arr` simply replace `index` with `rindex`.

See [Array#delete_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at), [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-index) and [Array#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-rindex).

Answer (score 1):

```
a.reject!{|str| str.casecmp("AB").zero?}
```

`casecomp` is the case-insensitive version of `String#<=>`.
 `a.reject!{|str| str.casecmp("ab").zero?}` behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `casecmp`. It reads much better than downcasing or upcasing one (sometimes both) of the strings being compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) instead, like this:

```
bad_string_downcase = bad_string.downcase
a.reject! { |element| element.downcase == bad_string_downcase }
```

Or using regex:

```
a.reject! { |element| element.match %r{^#{bad_string}$}i }
```