# How do only add item to an array if it doesn't exist already (in a case insensitive way)?

Tags: arrays, ruby, case-insensitive

I’m using Ruby 2.3.  I want to add an item to an array if the item doesn’t already exist, but defined in a case insensitive way.  So for instance, if my array is

```
a = [“A”, “b”, “c”]
```

and I want to add “d”, the result should be

```
[“A”, “b”, “c”, “d”]
```

but if I want to add “C”, the array should remain unchanged.  The order of elements added is imported and also something I want to preserve.  How can I add my item?

Comment: This previous question didn't help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962598/how-do-i-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-a-case-insensitive-way because the concept is nearly identical

Comment: I'm missing the connection.  That answer involves"delete_if".  But in this case, I'm tryihng to add something into an array.  What is the equivlanet expression I'm using?

Comment: all you are doing in your previous 3 questions is with the intent to search an Array in a case insensitive fashion and then either add, delete, or find the index of an element. If you haven't noticed all the answers to those questions use nearly identical syntax with slightly different methodology. You might be better served by simply looking at the documentation for Array rather than asking repetitive questions

Comment: The documentaion -- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html talks about "push" as far as adding a new element but it dones't have a "push_if" method.  You likely see something I don't and if so, plesae let me know the part of the documentation you're referencing.